# Centralized Log In Page of Intranet Web Applications

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I wonder what method should I use to create a centralized login page of our internal web applications. It should look like

Application 1 -> Login using Centralized Login Page -> Redirect to Application 1
Application 2 -> Login using Centralized Login Page -> Redirect to Application 2
Application 3 -> Login using Centralized Login Page -> Redirect to Application 3

So we won't find ourselves doing seperate login page for each apps.

What info should I pass from application to login page and vice versa?

Thanks,
Sherwin

Answer (score 1):

[Enabling Single Sign-on Using ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd577079.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, never knew that this kind of feature exists.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are looking for [Single Sign-On Enterprise Security for Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx)

You can refer to the following as well:

[Single sign-on with Forms Authentication](http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2004/06/09/ssoformsauth.aspx)

[Single Sign-on in ASP.NET and Other Platforms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SingleSignon.aspx)

Comment: Thanks body! never knew that this kind of asp.net feature exists xD.

Comment: Oh Singe Sign On still needs a login page from each web apps right?

Comment: @Sherwin: Not realy. You can build a seperate module for handling authentication/authorization ..

Answer (score 0):

Include a get variable called `redirect` (or whatever) and pass as much of the application url that you need.  After successful log in redirect to the information from that variable.